# finding text inside tags

Tags: parsing, search, text

Is there any simple way to implement a search that works inside  
I'd like to define name of tag and then get the results.

For example I'd like to find all occurrences  of "text" inside all  tags in my project and so on.
I am looking for a tool but I can also write my own script that does that.

Comment: Sure, use xpath to do so

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a really simple solution, so I am answering my own question.
Just use search tool and use wildcards. For example in my case I had to find text "CO2" inside a  tag. 
I did the following:
**CO2* 
where * replaces any string